# Jython UnboundLocalError - Tried the global type but still won't work

Tags: java, python, global, jython

I'm working on a emulator for Star Wars Galaxies and the scripting language that we're using is Jython. I'm having trouble figuring out how I define a variable outside the def. Here is the error..

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'actorFunds' referenced before assignment

And the code (cut out a lot that wasn't necessary... There is no class)

```
commandArgs = ""
commandLength = 0
globalTarget = SWGObject
globalActor = CreatureObject
tipAmount = 0
actorFunds = 0
totalLost = 0
bankSurcharge = 0

def run(core, actor, target, commandString):
    global globalTarget
    global globalActor
    global commandArgs
    global commandLength
    global tipAmount
    global bankSurcharge
    global actorFunds
    global totalLost

    globalTarget = target
    globalActor = actor
    commandArgs = commandString.split(" ")
    commandLength = len(commandArgs)
    tipAmount = commandArgs[0]
    bankSurcharge = int(0.05) * int(tipAmount)
    actorFunds = actor.getBankCredits()
    totalLost = int(tipAmount) + bankSurcharge

     .......
return

def handleBankTip(core, owner, eventType, returnList):

if eventType == 0:
    if int(totalLost) > globalActor.getBankCredits():
        globalActor.sendSystemMessage('You do not have ' + str(totalLost) + ' credits (surcharge included) to tip the desired amount to ' + globalTarget.getCustomName() + '.')
        return
    if int(tipAmount) > 0 and int(actorFunds) >= int(totalLost):
        return
return
```

When I get to actorFunds it provides the error...

I've searched for a long time and can't figure out why. I wish it was as simple as java with a "this"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the declared variable on the left hand side of the equation.

```
def run(core, actor, target, commandString):

    target = globalTarget 
    actor = globalActor
```

By writing:

```
globalTarget = target
```

You are assigning globalTarget with the value of target. Rather than creating a variable called target.

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I struggled over something so simple.